# R Plotly surface plot using frame to change the view

Tags: r, plotly

I would like to use R plotly to create an animation (by pushing a play button rather than dragging the plot) to spin around a surface plot (the volcano).

The code I currently have is as follows:

```
p <- plot_ly(z = ~volcano, type = "surface")

layout(p,scene=list(camera=list(up=list(x=0,y=0,z=1),
                                center=list(x=0,y=0,z=0),
                                eye=list(x=2,y=2,z=0)
                                )))

animation_slider(p, hide = FALSE)
```

I would like to adjust the values of `eye` within `camera` from the animation slider, so that it changes the plot without redrawing the whole plot. Note that this is a change in position of the camera not a change in data like most of the other examples in that are shown in the plotly documentation.

Is this possible?

**EDIT**

Using a shiny slider to animate I get the following...However this still redraws/re-renders the whole plot at each change of view, so the performance is 'jerky' or slow...I think using the `frame` argument would solve this, but not sure how...

```
# ui.R

library(shiny)
library(plotly)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Spining surface"),
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("deg", "degrees:", 
                min = 0, max = (360*3)+30, 
                value = 30,step=10,
                animate=animationOptions(interval=100))
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotlyOutput("surface")
  )
))
```

and

```
# server.R

library(shiny)
library(plotly)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$surface <- renderPlotly({

    p <- plot_ly(z = ~volcano, type = "surface")

    layout(p,scene=list(camera=list(up=list(x=0,y=0,z=1),
                                    center=list(x=0,y=0,z=0),
                                    eye=list(x=1.25*sin(input$deg*(pi/180)),
                                             y=1.25*cos(input$deg*(pi/180)),
                                             z=1.25)
                                    )))

  })

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this efficiently, you (at least currently) need to work on the JavaScript level. I just added a demo to help demonstrate -- https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/commit/d1f7f091424d807e1f1373643ba79b1b38943cf7